# I am getting a type error when looping JSONArray in Android / Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I want to access posters and loop it in this JSON sting.

```
{"r":
    {"posters":
       [
        {"rev":10,"poster_id":4,"poster_filename":"545397373c2c7","poster_filepath":"\/poster_files\/545397373c2c7","poster_synopsis":"This is the new synopsis for this exquisite poster I have created. You will marvel at its greatness and ask many questions.","poster_title":"Poster A"},
        {"rev":6,"poster_id":7,"poster_filename":"5453b54b83b5f","poster_filepath":"\/poster_files\/5453b54b83b5f","poster_synopsis":"This is a synopsis that is not real. No one can say what this synopsis really means. It is total B.S..","poster_title":"Poster A"}
       ],
"msg":"72 & 2",
"status":"complete"}
}
```

I have this to convert the string to JSONObject:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);         

JSONObject r = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("r"));

JSONArray posters = r.getJSONArray("posters");
```

Android Studio says "Array type expected, found org.json.JSONArray when I try to loop posters:

```
 int arraySize = posters.length();

 TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_download_list);

 for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
     myTextView.append(posters[i]);
     myTextView.append("\n");
 }
```

Am I not converting the object correctly??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);         

JSONObject r = jsonObject.getJSONObject("r");

JSONArray posters = r.getJSONArray("posters");
```

I changed the *r* **JSONObject** to get it from the **JSONObject** called *r* instead of calling **string** called *r* ,, because *r* in the json string is an object

**Update**

Change first line in the loop to be `myTextView.append(posters.getJSONObject(i).getString("poster_title"));` , this will print the poster title on each text view.

- the problem here is that you are dealing with the JSON array as an ordinary array.

Comment: Ahh...Thank YOU!!   Is writing "new" not required when creating the object?

Comment: Yes new need to be used if you want to use the constructor. Please if the answer is correct mark as best answer to mark ur question as answered

Comment: strang, I am still getting the type error in the for loop